# In pymongo: How can I append new dict in an existing array

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I found multiple tutorials about pushing a new element on pymongo array, but unfortunately, none of these worked for me.

*I have a document something like this*

```
{
    "_id": "14487152",
    "added_by": [
        {"name": "Gumi", "user_id": 70658401}
    ]
}
```

and this is what I am doing to insert a new dict in `added_by` array:

```
def find_product(self, _id):  # Find by Id
    data = self.collection.find_one({"_id": _id})
    return data

def add_new_product(self):
    self.collection.update_one(
        {"_id": self.find_product(_id=product['_id'])},
        {"$push": {"added_by": [{"name": "Harshil", "user_id": 7258757}]}},
        upsert=False)
```

*but by doing this, It creates a new document and starts appending something like this*

```
{
    "_id": {
        "_id": "14487152",
        "added_by": [
            {"name": "Gumi", "user_id": 70658401}
        ]
    },
    "added_by": [
        [
            {"name": "Harshil", "user_id": 7258757}
        ]
    ]
}
```

**So what exactly do I want to achieve?**
-- I want to append `{"name": "Gumi", "user_id": 70658401}` in existing document inside `"added_by"`

*Here is the output I am expecting*

```
{
    "_id": "14487152",
    "added_by": [
        {"name": "Gumi", "user_id": 70658401},
        {"name": "Harshil", "user_id": 7258757}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Was `upsert` set to `True` at one point?

Comment: Your `find_product()` returns a lot more than an `_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i 'll write something like this:

```
def add_new_product(self):
    data = self.find_product(_id=product['_id'])
    newvalue = {"$push": {'added_by': {"name": "Harshil", "user_id": 7258757}}}

    self.collection.update_one({"_id": data['_id']}, newvalue)
```